# transfering the project to enrolled account xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store, bundle, identifier

I recently finished my xcode project and wanting to submit on the app store. the problem that I'm having is I enrolled the apple developer program like two days ago. and saw some turorials to get it on the app store but I'm stuck at passing my app id(Bundle identifier) on the register app id section. Like I don't see any my project in the account and no idea how to get my project on the app store. Do I have to recreate the project as the enrolled account? or is there any way to get my finished project on the newly enrolled account?

Comment: Do you have the paid developer program ?

Comment: Yes, i paid around 100 dollars in local currency.

Comment: Did you create the App Id, App Store profile for your account .. ?.

Comment: If that is Register iOS App IDs, yes. That's what im trying to do and struggling. I see my name in the Preference as an Agent also my name as a user. No idea why this isnt working:(

Comment: Just go through this link once.. whether you followed the respective steps...

http://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/

Comment: Thank you for you link. But i actually tried this before and not working.  Im seeing following error message from the apple developer An App ID with Identifier PROJECTNAME is not available. Please enter a different string. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: hm.. try with the reverse domain string, like.. com.YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME.APP_NAME.. 
Using this style, most of this kind of issues will never come....